# How to add parameters to callback functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
renderingContent:function(widget){
    uilayer.confirm("", this.renderingContextWidgetOnOkClick,this.contextChangeCancelHandler);
}

renderingContextWidgetOnOkClick:function(widget){
        console.log(widget);
}
```

How do I pass widget parameter which I get in renderContent function to the callback this.renderingContextWidgetOnOkClick which gets invoked on click of OK as I cannot call this.renderingContextWidgetOnOkClick(widget) as then the function gets invoked directly without ok clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap it in a function

```
renderingContent:function(widget){
    uilayer.confirm("",   
        (function(that, widget){ 
            return function(){
                that.renderingContextWidgetOnOkClick(widget);
            };            
        })(this, widget),this.contextChangeCancelHandler);
}
```

Comment: well done, but you forgot that the context will be switched to your function, so `this` will not be the object anymore. You must remember it before calling `uilayer.confirm`. Anyway, +